# Блокировка функции(onclick) до завершения анимации

Tags: javascript

Нужно достичь эффекта, что бы при многократном нажатии на кнопку далее или назад, сначала завершалась анимация, потом осуществлялся переход к следующему слайду.

Я кликаю раз 5 на кнопку далее, с первого клика начинается анимация и пока она не завершиться остальные клики не обрабытываются.

ВАЖНО!: Пожалуйста чистый JS, я так понимаю это должна делать функция setTimeout, но не понимаю как.

```js
var slideWidth = 300;
var sliderList = document.querySelector('.slider__list');
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slider__item');
var btnPrev = document.querySelector('#prev_slide');
var btnNext = document.querySelector('#next_slide');
var pos = 0;

sliderList.style.width = slides.length * slideWidth + 'px';

btnPrev.onclick = scrollToPrev;
btnNext.onclick = scrollToNext;

function scrollToPrev() {
  pos--;
  if (pos < 0) {
    var children = sliderList.children;

    sliderList.style.transition = null;
    sliderList.style.left = -(pos + 2) * slideWidth + 'px';
    sliderList.insertBefore(children[slides.length - 1], children[0]);
    pos++;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(function() { //ожидаем следующего запланированного reflow/repain;
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      //предыдущий reflow рассчитал новый dom элемент
      //можно делать анимацию.
      sliderList.style.transition = 'left 0.6s ease-in-out';
      sliderList.style.left = -(slideWidth * pos) + 'px';
    })
  });
}

function scrollToNext() {
  pos++;
  if (pos > slides.length - 1) {
    sliderList.style.transition = null;
    sliderList.style.left = -(pos - 2) * slideWidth + 'px';
    var cloneElem = sliderList.children[0].cloneNode(true);
    sliderList.appendChild(cloneElem);
    sliderList.removeChild(sliderList.children[0]);
    pos--;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(function() { //ожидаем следующего запланированного reflow/repain;
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      //предыдущий reflow рассчитал новый dom элемент
      //можно делать анимацию.
      sliderList.style.transition = 'left 0.6s ease-in-out';
      sliderList.style.left = -(slideWidth * pos) + 'px';
    })
  });

}
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.slider__container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider__list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100px;
  list-style: none;
}

.slider__item {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.slider__arrows {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px auto
}

.slider__arrow {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider__container">
      <ul class="slider__list" data-current="0">
        <li class="slider__item">Слайд 1</li>
        <li class="slider__item">Слайд 2</li>
        <li class="slider__item">Слайд 3</li>
        <li class="slider__item">Слайд 4</li>
        <li class="slider__item">Слайд 5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='slider__arrows'>
      <button class='slider__arrow' id="prev_slide">Назад</button>
      <button class='slider__arrow' id="next_slide">Вперед</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одно из простых решений это включать и выключать флаг обозначающий проигрывание анимации. Например

```js
btnPrev.onclick = scrollToPrev;
btnNext.onclick = scrollToNext;

var animationInProgress = false;

function scrollToPrev() {
  // не обрабатываем нажатия, если анимация проигрывается
  if (animationInProgress) {
    return false;
  }

  /* ... */
  
  // запуск анимации
  sliderList.style.transition = 'left 0.6s ease-in-out';
  sliderList.style.left = -(slideWidth * pos) + 'px';
  
  // установка флага
  animationInProgress = true;
  // когда анимация закончится флаг нужно снять
  setTimeout(function(){ animationInProgress = false; }, 600);
  
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!